# How to find the big-theta for a growth function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

Is it possible to find the big theta of the growth function :
$$f(n) = \frac{5*n * 2^n + n^3 + 1}{n+5}$$

I know I need to show this function to be a set of big O and big Omega but i do not know how to start

Comment: Is it a full task? i'm asking because the function is a Big Theta for itself, you don't need to find anything

Comment: Yes it is a full task.

Comment: check for $2^n$